# Multiplying two columns in different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Items

```
Id    quantity  price
01     200        100
02     200        300
```

Transaction

```
Id Quantity 
01   1
```

But when I multiply the output is

```
Total
100
300
```

My query is select items.p*transaction.quantity as total from items,transaction

Comment: **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the query you are using. Do **not** post code in comments

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Share the query which you have used to multiply the values

Comment: Select item.p*transaction.s as total from item,transaction

Answer (score 0):

It this what you want?

```
select (t.quantity * i.price) as total
from transactions t join
     items i
     on t.id = i.id;
```

It seems really strange that the two tables, though, would be connected on `id`.